# javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace

Tags: xml, web-services, rest, soap, cxf

I have created Rest/Soap service with **apache-cxf-3.1.2** in **eclipse IDE** , and while using the service sometime i am getting the below exception repeatedly at server side.

```
    DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace 
    Location:  node: [wsd:Types: null]
    javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
    - with linked exception:
    [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:740)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:770)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:766)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:819)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:814)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.processValue(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:140)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.ListTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(ListTransducedAccessorImpl.java:155)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:65)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:589)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.text(InterningXmlVisitor.java:93)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.processText(SAXConnector.java:213)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:176)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:255)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBUtils.unmarshall(JAXBUtils.java:187)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider.invoke(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:502)
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.discovery.internal.WSDiscoveryServiceImpl$WSDiscoveryProvider.invoke(WSDiscoveryServiceImpl.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:180)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.performInvocation(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:66)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(AbstractJAXWSMethodInvoker.java:232)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:85)
    at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:74)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.udp.UDPDestination$MCastListener$2.run(UDPDestination.java:114)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:428)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:353)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix wsdp is not bound to a namespace
    at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:369)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$23.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:817)
    ... 41 more
```

I have done below to make it resolved , but it does't helped me out,

1. Cleaned and build the project.
2. enabled the build automatically option.
3. Deployed the service in tomcat separately(outside eclipse)

**Further Details:**

Eclipse version : Mars Milestone 1 (4.5.0M1)

JDK/JRE Version : 1.7.0_75

CXF version : 3.1.2

**Question:**

- I have read as it is the issue with CXF 3.1.2, So need to use CXF from 2.7 to 3.0 version is this true ?
- Is there any way to resolve this issue in CXF 3.1.2 version?

**Note :** This exception does't breaks any functionalities , But it is annoying to see this exception repeatedly.

Thanks,